# Struct with pointers changes value without reassigning

Tags: c, recursion, memory

I debugged the program below. It finds the correct result but then `mmat` in the recursive function `ri` gets changed without reassigning it by this part of the code `pmat[q][h].ptes=NULL;` and `i` get as final result that all the non pre-assigned pointers are null. I got the same problem with a global variable `mat **mmat` instead of passing it by reference in `ri`. Does anybody know the reason?

```
typedef struct tes_{
struct seg_{
    char c;
    int v;
}seg[2];
}tes;

typedef struct mat_{
    tes *ptes;
    int rot;
}    mat;

int max=0;

int main()
{
    FILE *f; char frase[M], buff[M]; int n,i,j,r,c,q=0,z=0,e=0,*pos,*esc; tes *vtes; mat **pmat, **mmat;
    printf("Inserire nome file input tessere: "); scanf("%s",frase);
    f=fopen(frase,"r");
    if (f==NULL) exit(1);
    fgets(frase,50,f); sscanf(frase,"%d",&n);
    vtes=malloc(n*sizeof(tes));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {fgets(frase,M,f); sscanf(frase,"%c %d %c %d",&(vtes[i].seg[0].c),&(vtes[i].seg[0].v),&(vtes[i].seg[1].c),&(vtes[i].seg[1].v));}
    fclose(f);
    printf("Inserire nome file input scacchiera: "); scanf("%s",frase);
    f=fopen(frase,"r");
    if (f==NULL) exit(1);
    fgets(frase,M,f); sscanf(frase,"%d %d",&r,&c);
    esc=(int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));
    pmat=(mat **)malloc(r*sizeof(mat *));
    mmat=(mat **)malloc(r*sizeof(mat *));
    for (i=0;i<r;i++) {pmat[i]=(mat *)malloc(c*sizeof(mat));    mmat[i]=(mat *)malloc(c*sizeof(mat));}
    for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
        fgets(frase,M,f); q=0;
        for (j=0;j<c;j++) {
            z=0;
            while (frase[q]!='/') {
                buff[z]=frase[q];   q++; z++;
            }
            q++;    buff[z]='\0';    z=0;
            if (atoi(buff)==-1) pmat[i][j].ptes=NULL;
            else {pmat[i][j].ptes=&(vtes[atoi(buff)]);  esc[e]=atoi(buff);  e++;}
            while (frase[q]!=' ' || frase[q]=='\n' || frase[q]=='\0') {
                buff[z]=frase[q]; q++; z++;
            }
            q++;    buff[z]='\0';    pmat[i][j].rot=atoi(buff);
        }
    }
    pos=(int *)malloc((n-e)*sizeof(int)); q=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { // pos contiene tutte le tessere inseribili
        for (j=0;j<e;j++) if(esc[j]==i) break;
        if (j>=e) {pos[q]=i; q++;}
    }
    ri(pmat,&mmat,vtes,pos,n-e,r,c);
    printf("Max valore %d\n",max);
    for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<c;j++) {
            printf("%c %d // %c %d\t",mmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(0+mmat[i][j].rot)%2].c,mmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(0+mmat[i][j].rot)%2].v,mmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(1+mmat[i][j].rot)%2].c,mmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(1+mmat[i][j].rot)%2].v);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void ri(mat **pmat, mat ***mmat, tes *vtes, int *pos, int i, int r, int c){
    int j,q,h,z,*pos2;
    if (i==0) {
        if(check(pmat,vtes,r,c)) {
                *mmat=pmat;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
        for (q=0;q<r;q++) {
            for (h=0;h<c;h++) {
                if (pmat[q][h].ptes==NULL) break;
            }
            if (h<c) break;
        }
        if (q==r && h==c) return;
        pos2=malloc((i-1)*sizeof(int));
        for (z=0;z<i;z++){
            if (z<j) pos2[z]=pos[z];
            else if (z>j) pos2[z-1]=pos[z];
        }
        pmat[q][h].ptes=&(vtes[pos[j]]);
        pmat[q][h].rot=0;
        ri(pmat,mmat,vtes,pos2,i-1,r,c);
        pmat[q][h].rot=1;
        ri(pmat,mmat,vtes,pos2,i-1,r,c);
        free(pos2);
        if ((*mmat)[0][1].ptes==NULL) {
            printf("prob");
        }
        pmat[q][h].ptes=NULL;
        if ((*mmat)[0][1].ptes==NULL) {
            printf("prob");
        }
    }
}

int check(mat **pmat,tes *vtes, int r, int c){
    int i,j, cont=0;
    for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<c-1;j++) {
            if (pmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(0+pmat[i][j].rot)%2].c!=pmat[i][j+1].ptes->seg[(0+pmat[i][j+1].rot)%2].c) break;
        }
        if (j==c-1) {for (j=0;j<c;j++) cont+=pmat[i][j].ptes->seg[(0+pmat[i][j].rot)%2].v;}
    }
    for (i=0;i<c;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<r-1;j++) {
            if (pmat[j][i].ptes->seg[(1+pmat[j][i].rot)%2].c!=pmat[j+1][i].ptes->seg[(1+pmat[j+1][i].rot)%2].c) break;
        }
        if (j==r-1) {for (j=0;j<r;j++) cont+=pmat[j][i].ptes->seg[(1+pmat[j][i].rot)%2].v;}
    }
    if (cont>max) {
        max=cont;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vtes=malloc(n*sizeof(tes));` -- This is not C++ code.  Please change the tag to `C`.

Comment: Just to be more specific, the reason why this can not be C++ code is that `malloc` requires the return value to be casted to the type.  There is no casting done on that line, and only a `C` compiler would allow this.

Comment: The reason is a bug somewhere in this fragile C program that results in memory corruption. The shown code is not really type-safe C++ code, but fragile C code that lacks many of the type-safety features of modern C++ and, as such, it's quite easily for a plethora of classical bugs, like dangling pointer dereferences, buffer overruns, and use-after-free, to slip through, making the resulting undefined behavior extremely hard to debug. The shown code is not salvageable, and should be completely scrapped and rewritten from scratch using modern, type-safe C++.

Comment: Any tips on how to write safer code? Thanks

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni -- First, are you really using C or C++?  You had originally tagged this question as C++ and the tag was eventually changed to C.  If you truly are using a C++ compiler, and only wrote C code because, frankly, you just didn't know any wiser, then state that your goal is to write a C++ program -- C++ has much safer constructs.  Otherwise, you can encapsulate the creation of the 2d and 3d arrays by creating functions to do this, instead of having code that has pointers all over the place.

Comment: C++ tag was a mistake, original code was in C